# Best-practice for javascript configuration on new web project

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, configuration-files

I would like to ask a question about a new and large scale web project's javascript requirements. We will use lot of javascript, ajax requests, jquery, json objects & jquery plugins in our project. We planning to store global variables and lot of default values in a global site configuration file with php class and ini file on server-side.

But we need to read, use and sometimes override some variables and configuration values on client-side with javascript - jquery.

This javascript based configuration file must have following properties;

- Won't have all server-side config values. Only we need.
- Must be a single file that will be call on html head section.
- Must define a global variable or json or javasctipt object or array (I don't know which is best)
- This values must reachable by other javascript functions and objects.
- Will store booleans, strings, integers maybe a some little initialization methods for 5-6 different pages (ex.: we don't need main page's config values on product detail page's and we don't need product detail page's some initialization methods and values on main page etc.)
- We need to reach some values of this configuration object on every page like debugMode=true or false etc..
- We need to know in other javascript objects to running platform via this config file for images and other resource paths (Developer-Test-Stage-Production)

Also we can completely generate this file on server side or generate a static .js file and after a PHP request, set some user-page-specific or language specific values, than we must be put (override) some of this server-side generated values in Js object.

What is best-practices for this solution? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Must define a global variable or json
>     or javasctipt object or array (I don't
>     know which is best)

JSON is basically an object literal, so it can do both. Go for it. Think of JSON as a serialized javascript object.

> - This values must
>     reachable by other javascript
>     functions and objects.

As soon as you run the JSON it will be available in your code.

> - Will store
>     booleans, strings, integers maybe a
>     some little initialization methods for
>     5-6 different pages (ex.: we don't
>     need main page's config values on
>     product detail page's and we don't
>     need product detail page's some
>     initialization methods and values on
>     main page etc.)

Again, JSON can do all of that.

So I would suggest a JSON file, that is included via script tag on the client side. JSON is easy to generate, read and manipulate on the server side (eg.: `json_encode`, `json_decode` in php).

It SHOULD BE a static js file, as it stresses the server the least. Also, Gzip compression can help to keep the bandwidth cost low.